# Docker Service is not up and running

Tags: docker

While we install the metadata in ubuntu(VMware) ..... after the environment setup when we give this command to start the metadata
`metadata docker --start`
Then the error is shown is this:

```
Docker Service is not up and running.
```

Can anyone give a solution to this error?

I try to change the status of the Docker Desktop Service from manual to running but I don't find any solution to change the status.

Answer (score 0):

This has happen because you have not enabled WSL distro to Ubuntu-xx.04 or default distro just turn it on Docker Desktop's UI find `SETTING>>RESOURCES>>WSL INTEGRATION>>Ubuntu-xx.04` and then click on `Apply & Restart` close docker restart it and try running `metadata docker --start` again, worked for me!